# Getting null pointer exception on getting Async Task JSON using Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to request a JSON with AsyncTask. I'm using loopj and AsyncTask

Here's my code:

```
 String str = null;   
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new TheTask().execute();
       }

       class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(Void... params)  {

          try{
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=Wa5sfwP3ku7c15qkZTsd**");
            client.get("http://*********.com/api/v1/***", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    str = response;
                   Log.v("==========RESULT==========", response); 
                }
             });
          } catch(Exception e){
             Log.v("========== ERROR ==========", e.toString());
          }
          return str;   
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          txt.setText("Result: " + result);   
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: where is your return statement in `doInbackground`??

Comment: can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: @Raghunandan updated my question. Is the onPostExecute means that the async is finished?

Comment: @Emmanuel java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: @AllenChun Are you sure your webservice functions right?

Comment: @crazyPixel I can see the result on logcat using Log.v("=== Result ===", response); but the TextView doesn't change the text

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: in which line, its showing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.
In your `doInBackground()` method you should use synchronous methods, and you are using asynchronous:

```
 client.get("http://*********.com/api/v1/***", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    str = response;
                   Log.v("==========RESULT==========", response); 
                }
```

That's why your `doInBackground()` returns null, and you are trying to deal with null in `onPostExecute()`

You should use methods from class `SyncHttpClient` from Loopj-Async library.